# How to improve file IO performance in a rest service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, file-io

The scenario I have at hand is from my spring boot rest service, read a word doc from resources folder and pass the byte array to the client

I read the word doc in memory using FileInputStream, convert input stream to a byte array using Apache Common IO IOUtils and place it in the response body of the rest service.

The problem here is that I always read the file in memeirh oer service request which is detrimental for there local memory of the process where service is running on.

I can’t read the file line by line and return it to the service caller in that fashion as I need to return the byte array back to the caller all together

Another problem I foresee is with how the file is read. I want to be a non blocking IO instead of a blocking IO.

Wondering what would be an efficient way to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need to read the file every time a request comes in.

Otherwise you could just read the file on server startup and then keep the file in memory stored in a Spring Bean. Then fetch it from there on every call?

Comment: I am thinking about somehow evicting it from the memory after serving the byte array. Not sure if there is a way to do that

Comment: Also, I need to think of a scenario when the document may change frequently. So loading it in spring IOC on start up may not work as fresh doc will have to be served for every request

Comment: depends on how the document will change. If the file is uploaded, you can upload it to the server, the server writes the file but keeps the file in memory. It can then serve the file from memory. If the server is restarted it just loads the file from disc on startup.

If the file is dropped in a folder, you can just use a filewatcher to read the file if it is dropped in a specific folder, and that in turn will load the file into memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to upload file every time, it's better to create the `@Bean`, doing that in init/postconstruct phase. You also can add some functionality to your `retrieve()` method, which checks and stores file modification time with invokation of `File.lastModified()` to decide whether you have to reload the content or not.